# Order of precedence in sequential XOR operations

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bitwise-xor

I have the following expression to calculate a parity bit:

AB0E XOR 73C9 XOR D46A XOR 06E3

How would this be evaluated? Is it:

(((AB0E XOR 73C9) XOR D46A) XOR 06E3)

or is it:

(AB0E XOR (73C9 XOR (D46A XOR 06E3)))

Comment: XOR is addition without carry, so the order is not important. AB0E XOR 73C9 XOR D46A XOR 06E3 = AB0E XOR 06E3 XOR 73C9 XOR D46A

Answer (score 18, accepted):

There is no difference; XOR is [associative](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associative_property).

Answer (score 0):

Since expressions have the same level or priority, so precedence will be left to right